# Excel require 7 digits in cell, allow for 0 at front of number

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2007, vba

I've got a cell that must contain a 7 digit number. To ensure that zero's do not get cut off from the beginning I've created a custom cell type with '0000000'. So now if I enter 0111111 it does not cut off the beginning zero.

Now I can't figure out how to make sure the person actually enters 7 digits. Setting a data validation with with whole number between 999999(6 digits) and 9999999(7 digits) doesn't work because the user could enter 0123456 which does not fit in that threshold.

Any ideas? -- I cant use VBA

Comment: Use a data validation from the Data tab with a formula `=AND(LEN(A1)=7,ISNUMBER(A1))` Where A1 is the upper left cell of the desired range to apply the validation.

Comment: Hi @ScottCraner I've got that working -- But this doesn't work with a 0 in the beginning

Comment: Add `'` before your numbers. It'll keep it all exactly as-is. (ie: `0000100`)  Maybe `="'"&AND(LEN(A1)=7,ISNUMBER(A1))`

Comment: @BruceWayne unfortunately that does not work

Comment: try `=AND(LEN(A1)=7,ISNUMBER(--A1))`

Comment: And make sure the cells are formatted as text not general.

Comment: @ScottCraner Thank you -- that seems to do the trick. ISNUMBER takes care of making sure its not text and it accepts the 0's in front now!

Answer (score 0):

1. Select the range where you want to enter numbers, go to 'Format Cells', select Custom, in the 'Type' field enter 0000000, press OK.
2. Select the same range, go to 'Data' Tab, click on 'Data Validation', in the 'Allow' drop-down menu select 'Whole Numbers', in the minimum field enter 0 and in the maximum field enter 9999999 and press OK.

Now if you enter 123, it will appear as 0000123.